# Unprotect VBProject from VB code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How can i unprotect my  VB project from a vb macro ?
i have found this code:

```
    Sub UnprotectVBProject(ByRef WB As Workbook, ByVal Password As String)
  Dim VBProj As Object
  Set VBProj = WB.VBProject
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Ne peut procéder si le projet est non-protégé.
  If VBProj.Protection <> 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = VBProj
  'Utilisation de "SendKeys" Pour envoyer le mot de passe.

  SendKeys Password & "~"
  SendKeys "~"
  'MsgBox "Après Mot de passe"
  Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

End Sub
```

But this solution doesn't work for Excel 2007. It display the authentification's window and print password in my IDE.

Then, my goal is to unprotect my VBproject without displaying this window.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: I'm calling this code from  VBModule who is  calling from java code using JACOB

Comment: `Java` means coffee to me and Jacob is an ol' friend of mine who died in his sleep... I have shown you how to automate `VBAProject Password`. I am sure you can take it off from here ;)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have never been in favor of `Sendkeys`. They are reliable in some case but not always. I have a soft corner for API's though.

What you want can be achieved, however you have to ensure that workbook for which you want to un-protect the VBA has to be opened in a separate Excel Instance.

Here is an example

Let's say we have a workbook who's VBA project looks like this currently.

[image]

**LOGIC**:

1. Find the Handle of the "VBAProject Password" window using `FindWindow`
2. Once that is found, find the handle of the Edit Box in that window using `FindWindowEx`
3. Once the handle of the Edit Box is found, simply use `SendMessage` to write to it.
4. Find the handle of the `Buttons` in that window using `FindWindowEx`
5. Once the handle of the `OK` button is found, simply use `SendMessage` to click it.

**RECOMMENDATION**:

1. For API's [THIS](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php) is the best link I can recommend.
2. If you wish to become good at API's like `FindWindow`, `FindWindowEx` and `SendMessage` then get a tool that gives you a graphical view of the system’s processes, threads, windows, and window messages. For Ex: uuSpy or Spy++.

Here is what Spy++ will show you for "VBAProject Password" window

[image]

**TESTING**:

Open a new Excel instance and paste the below code in a module.

**CODE**:

I have commented the code so you shouldn't have any problem understanding it.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
 
Dim Ret As Long, ChildRet As Long, OpenRet As Long
Dim strBuff As String, ButCap As String
Dim MyPassword As String

Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Const BM_CLICK = &HF5

Sub UnlockVBA()
    Dim xlAp As Object, oWb As Object
    
    Set xlAp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    xlAp.Visible = True
    
    '~~> Open the workbook in a separate instance
    Set oWb = xlAp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsm")
    
    '~~> Launch the VBA Project Password window
    '~~> I am assuming that it is protected. If not then
    '~~> put a check here.
    xlAp.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute

    '~~> Your passwword to open then VBA Project
    MyPassword = "Blah Blah"
    
    '~~> Get the handle of the "VBAProject Password" Window
    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "VBAProject Password")
    
    If Ret <> 0 Then
        'MsgBox "VBAProject Password Window Found"
        
        '~~> Get the handle of the TextBox Window where we need to type the password
        ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
        
        If ChildRet <> 0 Then
            'MsgBox "TextBox's Window Found"
            '~~> This is where we send the password to the Text Window
            SendMess MyPassword, ChildRet
        
            DoEvents
        
            '~~> Get the handle of the Button's "Window"
            ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Button", vbNullString)
            
            '~~> Check if we found it or not
            If ChildRet <> 0 Then
                'MsgBox "Button's Window Found"
    
                '~~> Get the caption of the child window
                strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr$(0))
                GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
                ButCap = strBuff
    
                '~~> Loop through all child windows
                Do While ChildRet <> 0
                    '~~> Check if the caption has the word "OK"
                    If InStr(1, ButCap, "OK") Then
                        '~~> If this is the button we are looking for then exit
                        OpenRet = ChildRet
                        Exit Do
                    End If
    
                    '~~> Get the handle of the next child window
                    ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ChildRet, "Button", vbNullString)
                    '~~> Get the caption of the child window
                    strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr$(0))
                    GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
                    ButCap = strBuff
                Loop
    
                '~~> Check if we found it or not
                If OpenRet <> 0 Then
                    '~~> Click the OK Button
                    SendMessage ChildRet, BM_CLICK, 0, vbNullString
                Else
                    MsgBox "The Handle of OK Button was not found"
                End If
            Else
                 MsgBox "Button's Window Not Found"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "The Edit Box was not found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "VBAProject Password Window was not Found"
    End If
End Sub

Sub SendMess(Message As String, hwnd As Long)
    Call SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, False, ByVal Message)
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout ,Thanks for your answer.But, When i try to execute this code it display the msg  "VBAProject Password Window was not Found"

Comment: `xlAp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsm")` What have you put here?

Comment: I have put the path of my file .xls like this Set oWb = xlAp.Workbooks.Open("C:\my file.xls")  Also the window of VBAProject  password still  displaying for me after appearance of  MsgBox "VBAProject Password Window was not Found"

Comment: I tested the above code in xl2003/2007/2010 and it works perfectly. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Sorry I do not know Java/Jacob so I won't be able to suggest anything there. Did you test the above code from a VBA module first?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28794/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-khalid-lblid)

Comment: + 1 You are on fire! another blog post? Naicccceeeee!

Comment: Hi Sid, I tried this, but unable to open the Password protected code. It's giving error **Project Locked** _invalid Password_ . Is anything need to be added. I am using 2007

Comment: @expfresh: Would recommend opening a new question with reference to this link. Also upload the code that you are actually using with a snapshot of the VBAProject Password windo :)

Comment: i trying this code in other environement but it generate a runtime error loading Dll at line  ` xlAp.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute`

Comment: Great solution @SiddharthRout, thank you. Do you have similar way to protect VBA project? I have 1000 excel file that I need to lock their VBA code from View. I have search a lot of forum but their solution always unreliable sendkey method.

Comment: @HarryDuong: Hi. I am out of town and will be back on the 6th. However, here is a [LINK](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/02/02/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window-part-ii/) which shows how to write to such kind of dialog boxes.

Comment: @SiddharthRout this isn't always working within code ;_; When I do `Set book = Workbooks.Open` the handle isn't been found. It works if I open a workbook manually (double click) but not via code. Please advise.

Comment: Siddharth, thanks for this great code! I just wanted to point to another possible solution, that enables unprotecting the VBProject from within its own code (i.e. not from a separate instance), in case someone else was in that situation like me. The code is from rory: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174982&page=2

Comment: @SiddharthRout I know this is an old question. But I tried your codes, but not working. It is showing the message `Invalid password`. Do you know any reason? By the way I changed the declarations to `PtrSafe`

Comment: yes. I tried a few methods including the other answer in this post. But none working. I am using latest office 365. Seems like many answers are outdated and only compatible with older versions of excel

Comment: Can you run `msgbox application.version` and tell me what do you see? @Anu

Comment: The version is 16.0

Comment: i just tested it in Excel 2016 (app version 16.0) and it works as required. I have 32 bit office @Anu

Comment: I am using 64 bit office. By the way for the `.xlsm` that I am trying to unlock have some compatibility error while opening. `Compile error in hidden module:`. Do you think in my case it is not working due to `64 bit` or this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219317/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-anu).

Answer (score 14):

I know you've locked this for new answers but I had a few issues with the above code, principally that I'm working in Office 64-bit (VBA7). However I also made it so the code would work in the current instance of Excel and added a bit more error checking and formatted it up to be pasted into a separate module with only the method `UnlockProject` exposed.

For full disclosure I really started with the code in [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174982&page=2#post_message_649012) although it's a variant on a theme.

The code also shows conditional compilation constants so that it ought to be compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit flavours of Excel at the same time. I used [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx) to help me with figuring this out.

Anyways here's the code. Hope someone finds it useful:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" (ByVal hDlg As LongPtr, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long) As LongPtr ' nIDDlgItem = int?
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetFocusAPI Lib "user32" Alias "SetFocus" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" (ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long) As Long ' nIDDlgItem = int?
    Private Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetFocusAPI Lib "user32" Alias "SetFocus" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uIDEvent As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Private Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10
Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Long = &HD
Private Const EM_REPLACESEL As Long = &HC2
Private Const EM_SETSEL As Long = &HB1
Private Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5&
Private Const TCM_SETCURFOCUS As Long = &H1330&
Private Const IDPassword As Long = &H155E&
Private Const IDOK As Long = &H1&

Private Const TimeoutSecond As Long = 2

Private g_ProjectName    As String
Private g_Password       As String
Private g_Result         As Long
#If VBA7 Then
    Private g_hwndVBE        As LongPtr
    Private g_hwndPassword   As LongPtr
#Else
    Private g_hwndVBE        As Long
    Private g_hwndPassword   As Long
#End If

Sub Test_UnlockProject()
    Select Case UnlockProject(ActiveWorkbook.VBProject, "Test")
        Case 0: MsgBox "The project was unlocked"
        Case 2: MsgBox "The active project was already unlocked"
        Case Else: MsgBox "Error or timeout"
    End Select
End Sub

Public Function UnlockProject(ByVal Project As Object, ByVal Password As String) As Long

#If VBA7 Then
    Dim lRet As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim lRet As Long
#End If
Dim timeout As Date

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    UnlockProject = 1

    ' If project already unlocked then no need to do anything fancy
    ' Return status 2 to indicate already unlocked
    If Project.Protection <> vbext_pp_locked Then
        UnlockProject = 2
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Set global varaibles for the project name, the password and the result of the callback
    g_ProjectName = Project.Name
    g_Password = Password
    g_Result = 0

    ' Freeze windows updates so user doesn't see the magic happening :)
    ' This is dangerous if the program crashes as will 'lock' user out of Windows
    ' LockWindowUpdate GetDesktopWindow()

    ' Switch to the VBE
    ' and set the VBE window handle as a global variable
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
    g_hwndVBE = Application.VBE.MainWindow.hWnd

    ' Run 'UnlockTimerProc' as a callback
    lRet = SetTimer(0, 0, 100, AddressOf UnlockTimerProc)
    If lRet = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "error setting timer"
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

    ' Switch to the project we want to unlock
    Set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = Project
    If Not Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject Is Project Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Launch the menu item Tools -> VBA Project Properties
    ' This will trigger the password dialog
    ' which will then get picked up by the callback
    Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=2578).Execute

    ' Loop until callback procedure 'UnlockTimerProc' has run
    ' determine run by watching the state of the global variable 'g_result'
    ' ... or backstop of 2 seconds max
    timeout = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, TimeoutSecond)
    Do While g_Result = 0 And Now() < timeout
        DoEvents
    Loop
    If g_Result Then UnlockProject = 0

ErrorHandler:
    ' Switch back to the Excel application
    AppActivate Application.Caption

    ' Unfreeze window updates
    LockWindowUpdate 0

End Function

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Function UnlockTimerProc(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As LongPtr, ByVal dwTime As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Function UnlockTimerProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Dim hWndPassword As LongPtr
    Dim hWndOK As LongPtr
    Dim hWndTmp As LongPtr
    Dim lRet As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim hWndPassword As Long
    Dim hWndOK As Long
    Dim hWndTmp As Long
    Dim lRet As Long
#End If
Dim lRet2 As Long
Dim sCaption As String
Dim timeout As Date
Dim timeout2 As Date
Dim pwd As String

    ' Protect ourselves against failure :)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Kill timer used to initiate this callback
    KillTimer 0, idEvent

    ' Determine the Title for the password dialog
    Select Case Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
        ' For the japanese version
        Case 1041
            sCaption = ChrW(&H30D7) & ChrW(&H30ED) & ChrW(&H30B8) & _
                        ChrW(&H30A7) & ChrW(&H30AF) & ChrW(&H30C8) & _
                        ChrW(&H20) & ChrW(&H30D7) & ChrW(&H30ED) & _
                        ChrW(&H30D1) & ChrW(&H30C6) & ChrW(&H30A3)
        Case Else
            sCaption = " Password"
    End Select
    sCaption = g_ProjectName & sCaption

    ' Set a max timeout of 2 seconds to guard against endless loop failure
    timeout = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, TimeoutSecond)
    Do While Now() < timeout

        hWndPassword = 0
        hWndOK = 0
        hWndTmp = 0

        ' Loop until find a window with the correct title that is a child of the
        ' VBE handle for the project to unlock we found in 'UnlockProject'
        Do
            hWndTmp = FindWindowEx(0, hWndTmp, vbNullString, sCaption)
            If hWndTmp = 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop Until GetParent(hWndTmp) = g_hwndVBE

        ' If we don't find it then could be that the calling routine hasn't yet triggered
        ' the appearance of the dialog box
        ' Skip to the end of the loop, wait 0.1 secs and try again
        If hWndTmp = 0 Then GoTo Continue

        ' Found the dialog box, make sure it has focus
        Debug.Print "found window"
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndTmp, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, 1, ByVal 0&)

        ' Get the handle for the password input
        hWndPassword = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, IDPassword)
        Debug.Print "hwndpassword: " & hWndPassword

        ' Get the handle for the OK button
        hWndOK = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, IDOK)
        Debug.Print "hwndOK: " & hWndOK

        ' If either handle is zero then we have an issue
        ' Skip to the end of the loop, wait 0.1 secs and try again
        If (hWndTmp And hWndOK) = 0 Then GoTo Continue

        ' Enter the password ionto the password box
        lRet = SetFocusAPI(hWndPassword)
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndPassword, EM_SETSEL, 0, ByVal -1&)
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndPassword, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, ByVal g_Password)

        ' As a check, get the text back out of the pasword box and verify it's the same
        pwd = String(260, Chr(0))
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndPassword, WM_GETTEXT, Len(pwd), ByVal pwd)
        pwd = Left(pwd, InStr(1, pwd, Chr(0), 0) - 1)
        ' If not the same then we have an issue
        ' Skip to the end of the loop, wait 0.1 secs and try again
        If pwd <> g_Password Then GoTo Continue

        ' Now we need to close the Project Properties window we opened to trigger
        ' the password input in the first place
        ' Like the current routine, do it as a callback
        lRet = SetTimer(0, 0, 100, AddressOf ClosePropertiesWindow)

        ' Click the OK button
        lRet = SetFocusAPI(hWndOK)
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndOK, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)

        ' Set the gloabal variable to success to flag back up to the initiating routine
        ' that this worked
        g_Result = 1
        Exit Do

        ' If we get here then something didn't work above
        ' Wait 0.1 secs and try again
        ' Master loop is capped with a longstop of 2 secs to terminate endless loops
Continue:
        DoEvents
        Sleep 100
    Loop
    Exit Function

    ' If we get here something went wrong so close the password dialog box (if we have a handle)
    ' and unfreeze window updates (if we set that in the first place)
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number
    If hWndPassword <> 0 Then SendMessage hWndPassword, WM_CLOSE, 0, ByVal 0&
    LockWindowUpdate 0

End Function

#If VBA7 Then
    Function ClosePropertiesWindow(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As LongPtr, ByVal dwTime As Long) As Long
#Else
    Function ClosePropertiesWindow(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Dim hWndTmp As LongPtr
    Dim hWndOK As LongPtr
    Dim lRet As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim hWndTmp As Long
    Dim hWndOK As Long
    Dim lRet As Long
#End If
Dim lRet2 As Long
Dim timeout As Date
Dim sCaption As String

    ' Protect ourselves against failure :)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Kill timer used to initiate this callback
    KillTimer 0, idEvent

    ' Determine the Title for the project properties dialog
    sCaption = g_ProjectName & " - Project Properties"
    Debug.Print sCaption

    ' Set a max timeout of 2 seconds to guard against endless loop failure
    timeout = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, TimeoutSecond)
    Do While Now() < timeout

        hWndTmp = 0

        ' Loop until find a window with the correct title that is a child of the
        ' VBE handle for the project to unlock we found in 'UnlockProject'
        Do
            hWndTmp = FindWindowEx(0, hWndTmp, vbNullString, sCaption)
            If hWndTmp = 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop Until GetParent(hWndTmp) = g_hwndVBE

        ' If we don't find it then could be that the calling routine hasn't yet triggered
        ' the appearance of the dialog box
        ' Skip to the end of the loop, wait 0.1 secs and try again
        If hWndTmp = 0 Then GoTo Continue

        ' Found the dialog box, make sure it has focus
        Debug.Print "found properties window"
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndTmp, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, 1, ByVal 0&)

        ' Get the handle for the OK button
        hWndOK = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, IDOK)
        Debug.Print "hwndOK: " & hWndOK

        ' If either handle is zero then we have an issue
        ' Skip to the end of the loop, wait 0.1 secs and try again
        If (hWndTmp And hWndOK) = 0 Then GoTo Continue

        ' Click the OK button
        lRet = SetFocusAPI(hWndOK)
        lRet2 = SendMessage(hWndOK, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)

        ' Set the gloabal variable to success to flag back up to the initiating routine
        ' that this worked
        g_Result = 1
        Exit Do

        ' If we get here then something didn't work above
        ' Wait 0.1 secs and try again
        ' Master loop is capped with a longstop of 2 secs to terminate endless loops
Continue:
        DoEvents
        Sleep 100
    Loop
    Exit Function

    ' If we get here something went wrong so unfreeze window updates (if we set that in the first place)
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number
    LockWindowUpdate 0

End Function
```

Comment: Wonderful! :) This method solves the main problem when working with the current Application instance: once the VBAProject Password Dialog is open, the Excel process is on pause, Excel is not in Ready mode, and VBE Main Window's caption have a trailing "[running]", meaning you can't do anything more than what has been scheduled before, and there won't be any more further code execution.

Comment: @ James MacAdie:  The single application instance code was very, very helpful.  Any chance you cooked up the reverse of this (to protect the VBProject programmatically)?  (Fingers crossed...)

Comment: Sorry no I didn't. The code I posted is extensively commented so it should be doable extend it to the process of re-locking a project, if you even need to go to the faff of using Win API calls. I'm a bit busy on the day job to look at it right now but will see if I can fit it in as a side project

Comment: If your Excel is not in Japanese or English, check the _"' Determine the Title for the password dialog"_ part of the code and add a Case for your language code (which you can easily discover by running _debug.print Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)_. In my case, the language is Portuguese, so Password is Senha. Then I added Case 1046 : sCaption = " Senha"

Comment: Complementing the above comment, you will also have to do the same with the sCaption inside _ClosePropertiesWindow_ function, because it will only be _" - Project Properties"_ if excel language is English.

Answer (score 0):

@James Macadie's answer (above) is the best I found (I'm running 32-bit Excel 365/2019)

**Note**: I found that you must have `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` in order to call James' method via a different sub or function. Otherwise, you may get an `Invalid procedure call or argument` error (if running outside of debug-mode).

This solution appears superior to both of the following:

1. http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2019/01/20/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/. creates a separate Excel Application instance to run the unlock process which didn't work for my use case
2. https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/lock-unlock-vbaprojects-programmatically-without-sendkeys.1136415/. unstable and would fail if run sequentially for multiple workbooks, I think due to a lack of the timer/waiting loops implemented in James' solution - I didn't thoroughly debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

Modification suggestion to James MacAdie's fantastic solution:

In the `Function UnlockTimerProc`, replace the code `pwd = Left(pwd, ...` with `pwd = VBA.Left(pwd, ...`, otherwise it fails with some books, which I've had a hard time figuring out. Thanks. Greetings.