# Debug.Assert behavior in MS Access runtime

Tags: vba, debugging, ms-access

In many compiled languages, calls to `Debug.Assert`, or their equivalent, are left out of the compiled production code for performance reasons.  However, calls to Debug.Assert still appear to execute in the `/runtime` versions of MS Access applications.

To test this, I added the following to my startup form:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Debug.Assert UserOK()
End Sub

Function UserOK() As Boolean
    UserOK = MsgBox("Is everything OK?", vbYesNo, "Test Debug.Assert") = vbYes
End Function
```

When I run this in a development environment and click [No] on the MsgBox, execution breaks at the Debug.Assert line (as I would expect).

When I run the same code with the `/runtime` switch (using a full version of MS Access 2002) I still see the MsgBox, but clicking on [No] does not halt program execution.  It seems VBA executes the line but ignores the result.  This is not surprising, but it is unfortunate.

I was hoping that Access would skip the Debug.Assert line completely.  This means that one must take care not to use Debug.Assert lines that would hurt performance, for example:

```vb
Debug.Assert DCount("*", "SomeHugeTable", "NonIndexedField='prepare to wait!'") = 0
```

**Is this behavior documented somewhere?**  The official documentation in Access appears to be pulled verbatim from VB6:

> Assert invocations work only within the development environment. When the module is compiled into an executable, the method calls on the Debug object are omitted.

Obviously, MS Access apps cannot be compiled into an executable.  **Is there a better alternative than the following workaround?**

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Not SysCmd(acSysCmdRuntime) Then Debug.Assert UserOK()  'check if Runtime 
End Sub

Function UserOK() As Boolean
    UserOK = MsgBox("Is everything OK?", vbYesNo, "Test Debug.Assert") = vbYes
End Function
```

Comment: I can't seem to find the link right now, but MS open sourced the office documentation recently. You may want submit a PR on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's any better for your particular use case, but there is an alternative that is better, if you're looking to do this in application agnostic VBA code. VBA has [Conditional Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240847(v=vs.60).aspx). Conditional Complication constants can be declared at the module level, but in this case, it will be better to declare it at the project level.

On the menu bar, click <kbd>Tools</kbd>>><kbd>Project Properties</kbd> and type a `DEBUGMODE = 1` into the "Conditional Compilation Arguments:" field. (*Note: `DEBUG` won't work as it's a keyword.*)

[image: Project Properties Dialog Window]

Now you can wrap all of your `Debug.Assert()` statements in code like this.

```
#If DEBUGMODE Then
    Debug.Assert False
#End If
```

When you're ready to deploy your project, just go back into the Project Properties dialog and change the argument to `DEBUGMODE = 0`.

Additional Information:

- [Utter Access has a fairly comprehensive article on Conditional Compilation](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Conditional_Compilation).
- [Directives - MSDN VB 6.0 Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338181(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I'm not sure it buys much over my existing workaround.  It does avoid the overhead of the call to `SysCmd(acSysCmdRuntime)`, but that's likely negligible anyway.  Also, I try to avoid using Conditional Compilation just because I have a terrible time remembering to switch the flags before deploying updates.

Comment: Your point about yours being an application-agnostic workaround is a good one (and one that I overlooked on first reading).  There's no real "runtime" equivalent in Excel, Word, Outlook, etc.  Conditional compilation is probably the only reliable workaround for those applications.

Comment: Yeah. I really don't think it really buys you anything in Access, but I don't think `SysCmd` is available in the other Office Applications, so this is the only "portable" way to do it that I know of.

Comment: You can also make your code do a lookup against a table value somewhere you set, so you can turn this on/off without redeploying a new runtime environment (depending on your use case). I have mine setup to do a "checkIfDeveloper" function based on my login so any "debug" stuff only happens for me or other developers.

Comment: @enderland: When you say you "can turn this on/off" is the "this" you are referring to the Debug.Assert or the conditional compilation?  If it's the latter I would be very interested in that, because I did not think there was any way outside of the IDE itself to make changes to global Conditional Compilation arguments.

Comment: @mwolfe02 it is actually possible to programatically make changes to global conditional compilation arguements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19801057/3198973

Comment: That's interesting, but it appears one would still need access to the IDE to make those changes.  That's not an option for a runtime Access environment.  Thanks for the link, though.  The technique of using `SendMessage` to interact directly with Windows elements from VBA was itself enlightening.  It's something that may come in handy in situations where I've previously felt forced to fall back on SendKeys {shudder}.