# How do you run macros upon opening Excel workbook, then re-protect after finished running?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to first, unprotect a workbook at the beginning of opening, run all the `workbook_open()` macros and then re-protect the workbook so that a common user can not change anything on any worksheets?  I'd like to prevent the common user from changing anything but allow the macros to do its auto-update and computations.

Any suggestions?  Is this even feasible?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code

Comment: `Workbook_Open` events are tricky to deal with, especially with multiple instances. I have seen one or two times where they screwed up my work as well. Instead of lining up `Open` events, what I did was use a first `Open` event and just placed everything else into a `Worksheet_Activate` event. Can this work for you?

Comment: Ensure your `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` is in `ThisWorkBook` Object. All the procedures can be stored in a regular Module (as long as not `Private Sub`). Also use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, avoid anything with `Active...`/`.Activate`/`.Select` in your codes. I would create `Unprotect`, `ReProtect` subs too.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I think the OP is referring to unprotecting a sheet/sheets, not unprotecting a VBA project (although that link is a great resource in the event the OP is referring to that). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is the `Worksheet.Protect` method.

At the beginning of your `Workbook_Open` event, place this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetYouWantToUnprotect").Unprotect _   Password:="TheSheetPassword"
```

Then at the end of your `Workbook_Open` event code, you want to protect the sheet again, so place this code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetYouWantToProtect").Protect _  
Password:="SheetPassword"
```

Of course, you can do this with more than one sheet if multiple sheets need to be unprotected. If each sheet has the same password, place a simple loop at the beginning of your `Open` event:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet  

For Each sht in Thisworkbook.Sheets  
    sht.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"  
Next sht
```

At the end of your code you can use the same loop to protect the sheets, just change `.Unprotect` to `.Protect`.

Or, if there are many different passwords (aside from recommending you change them all to one password), you can place as many instances of the first line of code I mentioned as it takes to unprotect the necessary sheets.

**Note:** There are **many** more optional arguments to the `.Protect` method which I did not cover, but you can find an exhaustive list [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx)

**EDIT:** [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221210%28v=office.11%29.aspx) more info on the `Unprotect` method.

Comment: How come when I stick in the ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll in between the unprotected loop and the "protect" loop I get the "cannot edit pivot table in protected sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    WS.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"
    WS.Protect Password:="YourPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next WS
End Sub
```

The `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` allows VBA to act on any part of your worksheets while the common user can only interact with "unlocked" cells.