# Unprotecting Microsoft Project VBA

Tags: vba, winapi, ms-project

I've modified the code for UN-protecting Excel VBA Project to work with Microsoft Project from the link below.

[Unprotect VBProject from VB code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/16176557#16176557)

But in MS Project there is always a Global.mpt(my code runs from here) and when the below line executes

```
projAp.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute
```

it always opens the VBA Project Properties of the Global.mpt file.

How do I select my Project Plan's VBA Project Properties?
Is there a Windows API function that would let me choose the second VBA Project Shown in the screen host. Launching the FindControl command after selecting the proejct should launch it corresponding VBA Project Properties(Manually tried this).

[image: Screen Shot of Project VBA]

Comment: I am not sure I understand but I think you need to iterate through VBProjects to get references to the right one since you are qualifying your `projAp` as VBIDE.Project possibly

Comment: @mehow I tried that now:
`debug.Print projAp.ActiveProject.VBProject.VBE.VBProjects.Item(1).FileName`
_C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MS Project\14\1033\Global.mpt_

`debug.Print projAp.ActiveProject.VBProject.VBE.VBProjects.Item(2).FileName`

_C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Project Plan v2.46.mpt_

`projAp.VBE.VBProjects.Item(2).VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute`

Even if I explicitly select the second VBAProject as in code snippet above the first VBA Project Properties only opens again.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to switch over to the Project pane and "type" the first letter of the project name; I suggest you change it from the default VBAProject if possible.

```
SendKeys "%{F11}"
SendKeys "^r"
SendKeys "V"
DoEvents
VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works,but not always. And I don't want to use Send keys as they don't work in all scenarios. Is there any other way to switch to the Project Pane and select the next Project?

Comment: The VBE does not expose any methods to select/activate a project. An alternative would be to enlist your users for assistance. Perhaps if the SendKeys fails, that could be the backup plan.

Answer (score 0):

projAp.VBE.CommandBars(1).

Your code is always working with the application object, so is always looking in the Global.mpt file. try:

ActiveProject.VBProject.VBE.CommandBars(1)

It should return only items for the project.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub UnprotectVBProj(fileName As String, modulePath As String, moduleName As String)
Dim Pwd As String
Dim vbProj As Object

Dim vbComp As Object



Set vbProj = Workbooks.Open(fileName).VBProject




If vbProj.Protection = 1 Then  ' already unprotected
Set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = vbProj
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "Planet282{(}{)}" & "{ENTER}" & "{ENTER}"




Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
 Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
Set vbComp = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import(modulePath)
vbComp.Name = moduleName
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveWorkbook.Close




End If



End Sub


'i did some like this which will add the modules
```

Comment: Please read [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).