# How to open properties for another workbook's VBA project in same instance?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a function that will unprotect a VBA project for a workbook that's open in the same instance as the workboook that has this function.  I'm trying to adapt Siddharth Rout's code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16176557/619177), but I can't figure out how to launch the specific VBA Properties window for the VBProject that I'm interested in unlocking.

As a test, I'm trying to iterate through the VBProjects in the instance to see which one corresponds to the desired workbook, and then open the VBA Properties window for that project:

```
Sub findVBProj()    

Dim prj As VBProject
Dim correctPrj As VBProject


For Each prj In Application.VBE.VBProjects
    If prj.filename = "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\testUnlock.xlsm" Then
        Set correctPrj = prj
    End If
Next

correctPrj.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(id:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute

End Sub
```

But this doesn't launch the VBA Properties window for `correctPrj` and therefore trigger the password prompt; instead, it opens the properties window for the project containing the module that contains `findVBProj()`, which makes sense because that module is selected when I run `findVBProj()`.  How do I make the properties window for `correctPrj` open?

Comment: As Siddarth Rout clearly states in his accepted answer (my emphasis):  "however you have to ensure that workbook for which you want to un-protect the VBA **has to be opened in a separate Excel Instance**.".

Comment: If you're going to do it in the same instance you need code like `Set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = correctPrj`. You don't actually need separate instances.

Comment: @Rory, have you tested this?  I was able to set the ActiveVBProject to `correctPrj`, but then the `.Execute` opened the Properties window for the main workbook instead.

Comment: Yes - it works fine for me in 2010. (and I have used similar code in 2003 in the past)