# Run AHK script from excel successfully

Tags: excel, vba, autohotkey

When trying to run a AHK script from excel the 1st way using shell

```
Sub FrmShell()
Shell ("C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe  \\REG-MITEK\Mitek\Mitek\documentation\RequestForQuote\old-RFP\RFP.exe")
End Sub
```

I get this error

[image]

When I run it with FollowHyperlink, 
it works but can't get away from the dreaded hyperlink warning.

```
Sub FromHyperLink()
Dim s As String    
s = "\\REG-MITEK\Mitek\Mitek\documentation\RequestForQuote\old-RFP\RFP.exe"    
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (s)
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Try open the Run menu (pressing Win+R) and run the `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe  \\REG-MITEK\Mitek\Mitek\documentation\RequestForQuote\old-RFP\RFP.exe` (without quotes). 2. Check that statement - you're trying to open one application with another, as far as I know - the syntax should be "Application_path fileToOpen_path". 3 Does `Application.DisplayAlerts` set to false help?

Comment: 1- same error popped up 2-Yep that did it, did not need to open AHK first,3-Displayalerts does not work for opening files with hyperlinks. If you want to answer this with #2 that would be great and I can check it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment, posting an answer:

> Check that statement - you're trying to open one application with another, as far as I know - the syntax should be "Application_path fileToOpen_path".

Possible decisions for #3 (requires registry access):

[Circumvent Hyperlink Security Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31927222/circumvent-hyperlink-security-warning)

and

[here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/disable-hyperlink-warning-in-excel-2010.491626/)

But I didn't try neither.