# Skip input box or any error message

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I run VBA from a temporary Excel workbook what it will do is "opens a macro enabled Excel in another path and extract value from cell C3 to the temporary Excel". But the problem is whenever I open Excel workbook from that path it will display two boxes.

1) Some error (I don't know that error name because macros are password protected in that Excel file otherwise suggest how to send "Enter" key, which skips this error.)

2) Input box (this case I need to just Enter, that's all.)

Is there any way to get data validation drop down values from other closed workbook without opening it.

```
Sub macro1()
 Dim wrk As Workbook
 Set wrk = Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\Test.xlsm") Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Range("h10") = wrk.Sheets(1).Range("c2").Validation.Formula1 wrk.Close SaveChanges:=False 
End Sub
```

Above is the code I am actually using now. But this code will open the file. I need values without opening the file.

Comment: Maybe look into [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266279(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of those two? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/16176557#16176557) is a reliable way to deal with those boxes. It uses APIS instead of Sendkeys

Comment: Sub macro1()

Dim wrk As Workbook
Set wrk = Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\Test.xlsm")
Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("h10") = wrk.Sheets(1).Range("c2").Validation.Formula1
wrk.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Above code i use it on temporary file. When try to open "Test.xlsm", it will show that 2 boxes I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sendkeys function is not working. I already tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSht, my_file
  my_file= Application.GetOpenFilename
If my_file = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.EnableEvents = False

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(my_file)
Set xlSht = xlApp.ActiveSheet

'YOUR CODE HERE

xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
Set xlSht = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

The key is   `xlApp.EnableEvents = False`, this will disable all macros on the other workbook.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please see the changed answer.

Comment: **Thank You Gedeon Kheboyan.** It is working for me. However I **tested** this case in my **home**. But real work is I need to **test** this case in my **official file** that is in my **office**. 

In my **reel** **test** it skipped the input box. This is superb.

But in my **real** **test** it will show 1 error message and 1 input box while file opening. So tomorrow I need to check this macro.

Comment: You are welcome. This code should skip any VBA code on the second workbook. So, I think it will not show you any error messages and inputboxes.

Comment: Excel cannot get data from other workbook without opening it. In my above-mentioned code excel will open the file in background so you will not see it.
`xlBook.Close False
xlApp.Quit
Set xlSht = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing`
this part will close the workbook after the process.

Comment: Gedeon Kheboyan I red about ExecuteExcel4Macro() function which will execute command in other excel files without opening the workbook. I don't know how to work with this function. That's why I asked.