# How can I send Shift + (Right Control Key) using VBA?

Tags: vba, sendkeys, shift, ctrl

I have a slightly less than usual application that we are writing an automation script against using VBA, and there is a need to send the keystroke +.

Is this possible? We can get the right ctrl key using Chr(1) but have not been successfully to add the shift keystroke to that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys should be `Application.SendKeys "+^{+}"` looks like

Comment: I will always advocate against doing this. There is a software called "AutoIT" that specializes in GUI interactions. It should only be used as a last resort and do not attempt to base a business process on this. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA: Why is API better than SendKeys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133729/excel-vba-why-is-api-better-than-sendkeys)