# Run-time Error '50289': Can't perform operation since the project is protected

Tags: excel, vba, project

This `error` only happens when the `VBProject` is `locked for viewing` and I understand that `Password Protection` of any kind is like `Door Locks`, it is designed to `Keep Honest People Out`!

[image: Run-time error 50289]

This error only happens when a call is is made to the following function which references the VBIDE Library:

```
Function chgWsCodeName(strName, cName, Optional WB As Workbook)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.vbProject
Dim vbComps As VBIDE.VBComponents
Dim vbComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim vbProps As VBIDE.Properties
Dim CodeNameProp As VBIDE.Property
If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets(strName)
Set VBProj = WB.vbProject
Set vbComps = VBProj.VBComponents
Set vbComp = vbComps(ws.CodeName)
Set vbProps = vbComp.Properties
Set CodeNameProp = vbProps("_Codename")
CodeNameProp.Value = cName

End Function
```

I'm not sure **why** the `Function` above causes the `Error` only when the `Project is Locked for viewing` and I have been unable to find an answer to that question! I believe I have all the necessary references selected in `Tools/References`.

[image: Tools/References]
This is the link to the code I use to [Unlock the VBProject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43874193/18701211).
The only functions I have been able to find access the `VBProject Properties Window` and `VBProject.Protection` is only restored when the Workbook is Saved, Closed, and Reopened. Is there a method change `VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_none` back to `VBProject.Protection = vbext_pp_Locked` thereby restoring `VBProject.Protection` without closing and reopening the workbook? I have seen countless `threads` on different `Forums` stating it was impossible to access `VBProject Properties` programmatically through `VB` or `VBA` yet as one may see from  the Link to `Unlock VBProject` above, the `Impossible` is `Possible`!
Can someone **Please** help me with this?
Thanks in advance for your assistance!