# How can I re-protect an unlocked VBA project without reopening the Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have a VBA password protected project that I am able to programmatically unlock with code found in this [StackOverflow article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code)

I am trying to find a way (in VBA or any other programming language) to re-protect a VBA project after it has been programmatically unlocked using the code referenced above. *(I'm know that I can close the excel workbook and re-open it to have the project protected again, but that is not the goal. Nor do I want to write code to close and re-open the workbook.)*

I can't even find a way in the VBE UI to re-enable the project protection without closing and re-opening the entire workbook. So I am concerned that there may be no way to accomplish this programmatically. (If there is a way to do this through the VBE UI, I'd appreciate instructions on how to do that as well since I could then write the code following the excellent example code I referenced above!)

*UPDATE: short of an answer to this question, I've buried myself in a rabbit hole trying a workaround to programmatically open/close the workbook automatically (which I am successful in doing using Application.Ontime. I'm so deep in problems that others are having I fear if continue down this "workaround path" that I will end up, at best, with a very "kludgey" solution! I soooo wish Microsoft had implemented `(VBIDE) VBE.VBProject.Lock(<password>)` and `VBE.VBProject.UnLock(<password>)` to mimic the VBE UI Project Properties Protection tab functionality!!!*

The expected outcome would be to have to re-enter a password to view any code in the password protected project.  That behavior is modeled when closing and re-opening Excel, but that is NOT the desired solution!