# Excel Addin Project is not removed from VBE when the VBAProject that includes it is closed

Tags: excel, vba

Why is my Excel Addin project left open in the VBE Project Explorer window after I close the project that includes it as a reference?  See reproduction steps below using Office 365 Excel, and note that the ***desired behavior*** would be to have everything related to the workbook removed from the Project Explorer when the workbook is closed.  ***Acceptable solutions*** would include the equivalent of this functionality that is sadly missing in the VBIDE reference:

```
        `VBE.VBProject.Lock(<password>)`  
        `VBE.VBProject.UnLock(<password>)`   
        `VBE.VBProject.Close`
```

Background: I have developed a password protected Excel Addin (at the project level) which is purely for my own consumption.  The Addin needs to be password unlocked for various reasons. There is no way to relock it in the VBE UI, and there doesn’t seem to be a programmatic way to do it either [(Related Post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841481/how-can-i-re-protect-an-unlocked-vba-project-without-reopening-the-excel-workboo).  Noting that closing the Excel Application and reopening the workbook results in the Addin being locked again, I’m way down a rabbit hole trying to close and reopen the workbook programmatically.  I have that working using `Application.Ontime`, but the problem described herein still exists when the workbook reopens: the addin is still password unlocked (because the VBE never went away, the addin left in the VBE was unlocked, and when the workbook reopened, the addin was left unlocked - presumably because it was already there and unlocked)

So I’ve created the simplest steps I can think of to show how to reproduce the problem I’m running into.  Here’s the “worth a thousand words pictures:”

***Before the problem:***

[Basic empty project and addin needed to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgNiz.png)

***And the problem after reproduction:***

[Shows the problem after closing the workbook ("ThisWorkbook.Close" or little "x")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u8so.png)

***And here’s the thousand words if the pictures aren’t clear enough:***

*Steps to recreate:*

Create the empty Excel Addin:
1)      Create a brand-new workbook (.xlsx)
2)      Open the workbook in excel and open the VBE
3)      In the VBE, change the default project name from “VBAProject” to “EmptyAddin”
4)      Save the workbook as an Excel Addin (.xlam)

Include the Addin into an (almost) empty Excel Macro-Enabled workbook:
5)      Create another new workbook (.xlsx)
6)      Open this second brand new workbook
7)      In the VBE, double click the “ThisWorkbook” object in the Project Explorer to open a code window
8)      Create an empty “`Workbook_Open()`” subroutine (by selecting the “Workbook” object from the dropdown)

```
    `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`

    `End Sub`
```

9)      Select Tools -> References and browse to select the .xlam Addin created in step 4 above
10)  Verify that the reference called “EmptyAddin” (from step 3 above) is selected and select OK to include the reference in the workbook.
11) Confirm the contents in the Project Explorer window look like this:

[The basic project and addin after step 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYnUe.png)

12)      Save the workbook as a Macro-Enabled Workbook (.xlsm)
13)      Close Excel and the workbook

Delete the default VBAProject and observe the issue:

14)      Reopen the file saved in step 12 and go into the VBE. (accept any prompts to enable macros and treat the file as a trusted document)
15)      Confirm the Project Explorer matches the picture above
16)      Make sure the VBAProject is selected in the Project Explorer by clicking on “VBAProject”
17)      Open the Immediate Window
18)      Enter “ThisWorkbook.Close” and press return

At this point observe that the workbook opened in step 14 is now closed, but the Excel application remains running with VBE open and visible.

**ISSUE IS NOW SEEN:   The Addin is not closed and remains in the VBE Project Explorer.**

*Some Notes:*

-          If I try to close (using ThisWorkbook.Close in the immediate window) the Addin project in the Project Explorer ***before*** I have deleted the VBAProject project, I get an obvious error the “This workbook is currently referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed.”
-          Both the EmptyAddin Excel Addin and the Macro-Enabled Workbook are essentially empty, with the exception of the stubbed `Workbook_Open()` routine (which is the bare minimum change to an otherwise empty workbook that I could find to allow the referenced addin to be saved into the workbook.)  Therefore there should not be any reason to blame any programming errors in the VBAProject for leaving open references to the EmptyAddin addin!  (I’d be happy to be proven wrong and shown the error of my ways!)
-          Making `VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True` does not resolve the issue (the “EmptyAddin” project is still open)

*Interesting:*

If, after executing the reproduction scenario above, I then add a final step 19:

19)      Enter “`ThisWorkbook.Close`” and press return (in the Immediate Window)

The EmptyAddin project is then closed.  The fact that this works without an open workbook, and only the Excel Application and its VBE are open hints that the `ThisWorkbook` object is still alive somewhere and if Application (vs "workbook") level code could be written and executed, then that might be a solution.  I don't know where to do that if it's even possible.

I can think of a possible acceptable workaround based on step 19 above.  But I don’t know how to implement after the workbook is already closed (step 18).   But I will post that as a separate question so as not to pollute this questions focus on “Why is the project referencing my Excel Addin left open in the VBE Project Explorer window after I close the project that includes the Excel Addin?” And the ***desired behavior*** which would be to have everything related to the workbook removed from the Project Explorer when the workbook is closed.